# How to draw the following diagram in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-trees

[image: how to draw this picture in tikz]

i am getting problem drawing this type of tree using tikz and how to write two line labels for a node in tikz

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Jubobs notes, it's usually unlikely you'll get someone to make your picture from scratch, but I happen to have nothing better to do. So here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{bigtip/.style={-,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[line width=3pt]{stealth}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Bottom level
\node[circle,draw] (20) at (0,0) {20};
\node[circle,draw] (21) at (2,0) {21};
\node[circle,draw] (24) at (4,0) {24};
\node[circle,draw] (28) at (6,0) {28};
\node[circle,draw] (30) at (8,0) {30};
\node[circle,draw] (38) at (10,0) {38};
% Middle levels
\node[ellipse,draw] (20-21) at (1,1.5) {[20-21]};
\node[ellipse,draw] (28-30) at (7,1.5) {[28-30]};
\node[ellipse,draw] (20-24) at (3,3) {[20-24]};
\node[ellipse,draw] (28-38) at (9,3) {[28-38]};
% Top level
\node[ellipse,draw] (20-38) at ($($(20-24.center)!.5!(28-38.center)$)+(90:1.5)$) {[20-38]};
% Arrows
\foreach \x\y in {20/20-21,21/20-21,28/28-30,30/28-30,20-21/20-24,24/20-24,28-30/28-38,38/28-38,20-24/20-38,28-38/20-38}{
  \draw[bigtip] (\x)--(\y);
}
% Labels - bottom level
\node[anchor=north] at ($(20)+(270:.4)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}20,20,1\\lb,ub,freq\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(21)+(270:.4)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}21,21,2\\lb,ub,freq\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(24)+(270:.4)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}24,24,2\\lb,ub,freq\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(28)+(270:.4)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}28,28,1\\lb,ub,freq\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(30)+(270:.4)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}30,30,1\\lb,ub,freq\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(38)+(270:.4)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}38,38,3\\lb,ub,freq\end{tabular}};
% Labels - middle levels
\node[anchor=east] at ($(20-21)+(180:.7)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}lb,ub,freq\\20,21,3\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=east] at ($(28-30)+(180:.7)$) {\begin{tabular}{l}lb,ub,freq\\28,30,2\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=east] at ($(20-24)+(180:.7)$) {\begin{tabular}{c}lb,ub,freq\\20,24,5\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=west] at ($(28-38)+(0:.7)$) {\begin{tabular}{c}lb,ub,freq\\28,38,5\end{tabular}};
% Labels - top level
\node[anchor=west] at ($(20-38)+(0:.7)$) {\begin{tabular}{c}lb,ub,freq\\20,38,10\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

A few things to note:

- I adjusted the spacing of the nodes to make it (somewhat) more uniform
- The arrows point to the center of each node, not to the bottom. To make them point to the bottom, replace `\draw[bigtip] (\x)--(\y);` with `\draw[bigtip] (\x)--(\y.south);`.
- The size of the arrow tip can be adjusted manually, by changing `\arrow[line width=3pt]` to (for example) `\arrow[line width=2pt]` to make them smaller, in the `\tikzset` command at the top of the code.
- I'm not sure if you wanted all the text next to the nodes to be left adjusted, but I made most of them left adjusted, and some of them centered, as you have it. In the labels section, the `l` in `\begin{tabular}{l}` makes it align at the left side, and changing the `l` to a `c` makes it centered.
- I'm not sure how to get that red and green ridged underline you have for some parts. I feel like I've seen it somewhere, but it's been much too long.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Mr. jlv. It really helpful to me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, the tree produced using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package. Notice, in particular, the structured definitions for the tree at the beginning with the advantages they provide (code economy being one of them):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand\Mylabelt[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
#1 \\
lb, ub, freq
\end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\Mylabelb[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
lb, ub, freq \\
#1
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
where n children=0
  {tier=word,shape=circle}
  {shape=ellipse,before typesetting nodes={content=[#1]}
},
for tree={
  s sep=1.5cm,
  draw,
  edge={<-,>=latex},
} 
[20-38,name=ro,
  [20-24,name=l
    [20-21,name=ll
      [20,name=lll]
      [21,name=llr]
    ]
    [24,name=lr
    ]
  ]
  [28-38,name=r
    [28-30,name=rl
      [28,name=rll]
      [30,name=rlr]
    ]
    [38,name=rr
    ]
  ]
]
\foreach \Nombre/\Valores in {l/{20,24,5},ll/{20,21,3},rl/{28,30,2}}
  \node[anchor=east] at (\Nombre.west) {\Mylabelt{\Valores}};
\foreach \Nombre/\Valores in {ro/{28,30,10},r/{20,38,5}}
  \node[anchor=west] at (\Nombre.east) {\Mylabelt{\Valores}};
\foreach \Nombre/\Valores in 
  {lll/{20,20,1},llr/{21,21,2},lr/{24,24,1},%
   rll/{28,28,1},rlr/{30,30,1},rr/{38,38,3}%
  }
    \node[anchor=north] at (\Nombre.south) {\Mylabelt{\Valores}};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much Mr. Gonzalo Medina. It really helpful to me a lot.